# different results after certain limit

Tags: c

I am doing some exercises. There was a problem, where you have to do the sum of the squares of the first N natural numbers (lets call it x) and the square of the sum of the first N natural numbers (lets call it y). At the end what you want is the difference y-x.

I did following:

```
unsigned long long sumsquar(int limit){
  unsigned long long sum = 0;
  for(int i=1; i<limit+1; i++){
    sum += (i*i);
  }
  return sum;
}

unsigned long long squarsum(int limit){
  unsigned long long sum=0;
  for(int i=1; i<limit+1; i++){
    sum+=i;
  }
  return (sum*sum);
}


int main(void)
{
  int limit = 1024;
  unsigned long long sum1 = squarsum(limit);
  unsigned long long sum2 = sumsquar(limit);
  unsigned long long erg1 = squarsum(limit)-sumsquar(limit);
  printf("%llu\n", erg1);
  unsigned long long sum = (limit*(limit+1))/2;
  unsigned long long sum_sq = ((2*limit+1)*(limit+1)*limit)/6;
  unsigned long long erg2 = (sum*sum)-sum_sq;
  printf("%llu\n", erg2);
  return 0;
}
```

short explanation: I have two functions sumsquar and squarsum which calculate x and y.

For comparison reasons I also included the 4 rows above "return 0", because it is much faster with this solution.

Now the problem is, that for Ns (here limit) to 1023 I get the same result, but if limit is >1023 the results are not the same.
Why is this the case?

BTW sorry for the ugly title but I did not know what to use there...

Comment: yes it does. But why is this the case?

EDIT: Someone suggested changing all the ints to unsigned long long.

Comment: Isn't the point of answers to Project Euler questions that the answer is your own unaided efforts?

Comment: @WeatherVane I did it by myself and it works for the problem (where the limit is 100) but like I said after limit is >1023 it does not anymore. And that is what I am asking

Comment: That is the difference between the trivial solution and the expert solution: usually the latter answers the **real question**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you tell me why I have to change the ints to unsigned long longs?.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it well enough, but my question is about the C language. My limit is an int which can be far more than 1023. All the large values are saved in unsigned long longs. So it is not clear for me, why my results changes if my limit is > 1023

Answer (score 1):

Int is of size 4byte (The size of an int is really compiler dependent. Back in the day, when processors were 16 bit, an int was 2 bytes) considering you have 32 bit or 64 bit system. So max value limited to 0x7fffffff.

Where as unsigned long long is atleast 64 bits, or larger.

in your case, int is not enough to hold the sumsqare() when N > 303 - So your results will be incorrect if you use int for N>303 . 
If you use 64 bit, you can go much higher value of N. (Still there will be a limit)

Answer (score 0):

So someone in the comments suggested changing all the ints to unsigned long long. That fixed the problem, but I do not know why.

Edit: 
"Because you've got 64 bits, unsigned; but int is generally 32 bits signed" – Basile Starynkevitch

I tested it out. If you have:

```
  int aa = 2147483647;
  long bb = aa +1;
  printf("%d", aa);
  printf("%ld", bb);
```

aa=2147483647

bb=-2147483648

my mistake was I thought that if the variable in this case for example "sum" is an unsigned long long it is no problem because it is large enough

Comment: Because you've got 64 bits, unsigned; but `int` is generally 32 bits signed

Comment: Oh, so now I think I understand it. You can't do any operations with int if the  value of the result is exceeding 2147483647, even if the variable you are declaring it to is an unsigned long long. Is this right?